# chrome.windows.onRemoved fired after window is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and ran into a scenario where chrome window has been created and bunch of listeners are attached to the window which keep monitoring the window. Now if I close the window with cancel button of the browser window, I need to cleanup the listeners and then close the window.

So, I added a listener using `chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(integer windowId) {...});`
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onRemoved. But here comes the issue.
If I close the window the flow is `[Closing the window]` -> `[Firing the event]` but I would like to have the opposite `[Firing the event]` -> `[Closing the event]` so that I can clean up the listeners and then close the window.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload) or [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/unload) events on the Page.

## Reference

- [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload)
- [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/unload)